# CRM 4.0 - programatically re-opening a closed Incident/Case

Tags: dynamics-crm

I need to *programatically* re-open an Incident/Case that has been closed.
I have tried to do this by simply setting statecode & statuscode back to their starting values [link text](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms914670.aspx), but I still get a 'cannot perform this as entity is readonly' error.

Answer (score 2):

Using the CrmService, there are a number of [SetStatus](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc155990.aspx) methods for the built-in entities.

For Incident, you would use [SetStateIncident](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb959537.aspx) like this:

```
CrmService service = new CrmService();

SetStateIncidentRequest request = new SetStateIncidentRequest();

request.IncidentState = IncidentState.Active;
request.IncidentStatus = -1;

request.EntityId = <YOUR GUID HERE>;

SetStateIncidentResponse response = (SetStateIncidentResponse)service.Execute(request);
```

This code can be used in a plug-in, or other application (e.g. console app).